# AlertDialog not working properly

Tags: java, android, onclick, android-alertdialog

I am creating an AlertDialog which will ask the user to whether to delete the record or not ? so for that i have declare a global flag variable (above the onCreate() method)

> private int yes;

if user press **Yes** then value of yes will be 1 &
 if press **No** then value of yes will be 0

The Code of my AlertDialog is below

```
public int dialog()
        {
            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(DataListActivity.this);
            alertDialog.setTitle("Alert");
            alertDialog.setMessage("Are you sure to delete ?");
            alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                {
                yes = 1;
                }
            });
            alertDialog.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    yes=0;
                }
            });
            alertDialog.show();
            return yes;
        }
```

on the basis of this yes i want to delete the record but either i press yes or no, the value  of this flag int yes remains 0, See the LOGCAT

this one for press no

```
12-25 00:52:22.144 2133-2133/? E/Logggggggg::  0
```

this one for press Yes

```
12-25 00:52:33.408 2133-2133/? E/Logggggggg::  0
```

now i am checking the flag yes as,

```
     int dd = dialog();
     Log.e("Logggggggg: "," "+yes);
     if (dd == 1)
     {
        Boolean r = mydb.deleteData(selections);
     }
     else
     {
      /////// do Nothing;
     }
```

Can anyone tell me what's going wrong here..??

Comment: Actually what is happening that your method is displaying you alert dialog but as  alertDialog.show(); is called immediately after that yes variable is returned and you have written your yes variable changes in onClick() so you are not able to get your value of yes variable.

Comment: i didn't get you, and what should i do?

Comment: i think bellow answer will work for you.

Comment: okk..i will try that

Answer (score 2):

You cannot capture the value of `yes` as the return value of your method, because it has not been set yet at the time the return statement happens.  Instead, just do the database cleanup directly in the `onClick` listeners for the yes and no buttons, e.g.

```
alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        // delete the record here
        Boolean r = mydb.deleteData(selections);
    }
});
```

The above should be considered as pseudo-code, because I am not familiar with the details of your code base.  But the basic idea to respond the user selecting yes by directly handling that action in the `onClick` listener.

Comment: you are right sir..! but i want to delete the value from outside this dialog() method.

Comment: Yes, but _why_ do you want to do that?  You could set a boolean flag when closing the dialog, which would record that the dialog has been finished.  But again, I don't necessarily see the need to do this.

Comment: actually i am deleting the record through contextual view.. and all of the coding of deleting can't be outside.

Comment: public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
                if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_delete)
                {
                    dialog();
                    Log.e("Logggggggg: "," "+yes);
                    if (yes == 1)
                    {
                        Boolean r = mydb.deleteData(selections);

Comment: Then you need to create a handler that can send message

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
private void dialog() {
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    alertDialog.setTitle("Alert");
    alertDialog.setMessage("Are you sure to delete ?");
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            yes = 1;
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), String.valueOf(yes), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            yes =0;
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), String.valueOf(yes), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

checking flag

```
if(yes==1){

    Boolean r = mydb.deleteData(selections);
 }else
 {
  /////// do Nothing;
 }
```

Comment: it was insane,can't believe that..!  the toast giving 1 on YES and 0 on NO..it's fine and working  but still in log cat i am getting 0 always..whether i press yes or no.

Answer (score 0):

you may just need to use onClick() signature value i.e. `int which` and assign it `yes` value like below code

```
  public int dialog()
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(LoginActivity.this);
        alertDialog.setTitle("Alert");
        alertDialog.setMessage("Are you sure to delete ?");
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
            {
                which = 1;
                yes = which;
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"value : "+yes,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                which = 0;
                yes = which;
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"value : "+yes,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        alertDialog.show();

        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"value : "+yes,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return yes;

    }
```

Comment: it's not working.. and i think there's no way to get a value in return through AlertDialog.

Comment: All we can do is write the code in onClick() method of setPositiveButton and setNegativeButton.